# external application started by os.system() and subprocess.Popen() runs slower on Linux

Tags: python, linux, process

I've wrote a python script to start other application by using os.system(app_path) or subprocess.Popen(app_path, shell=False), but the application run slower than start the application directly from the shell (its a application with GUI so I can feel it obviously). is it the right way to start other application this way? If not, is there any better way to do so? 
The application do not have to interact further with the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `os.spawnl`, like this:

```
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, "path to script")
```